# console command result as input file for sed or other commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Some commands take a file as an input, is there a way to treat a result of a command as a file?

for example I want to get a string between 2 strings:

```
sed -n "/START-WORD-HERE/,/END-WORD-HERE/p" input
```

but I want to use a command that generates a lot of text as input for example 'cat somefile'
I tried replacing input with $(cat somefile) but sed returned an error for every word returned by the cat command...

Comment: Either a [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) or a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and this is the very core of the Linux Philosophy "Many small tools to make a larger process"

Linux uses something called command line pipes.

To use them, you simply join two commands together using the vertical bar character

```
|
```

So in your case, you said you wanted to send the output of the cat command into the sed command, you can do this as follows

```
cat somefile | sed -n "/START-WORD-HERE/,/END-WORD-HERE/p"
```

Notice, that in this case you DO NOT specify the file name after the command any longer.

99% of all Linux commands will allow you to operate using pipes, but be sure to read the man pages for some of them, as a good few of them require you to still specify the file-name to work with, but usually tell you to use a

```
-
```

(Minus Character)

In place of the file name.

Also remember that in most instances the pipe is linear, with the output of one end forming the input of the other, carrying any transformations performed along the chain.

This means for example, if you

```
cat somefile | grep someword | sed -n "/START-WORD-HERE/,/END-WORD-HERE/p"
```

The input to sed will only be the output from any operations that grep performed on the input from cat.

It's always best to test/experiment with a copy of the file first until you know you've got things correct, and don't be afraid to develop things one step at a time.

get the

```
cat blah | grep bleah
```

bit right, before adding the sed bit on.  Then get the sed bit right before adding the awk/wc/ whatever else bit on, watching the output a step at a time will allow you to debug and verify your pipe as you go.

There are many commands that do a great many different jobs, and it's a great excuse to spend an evening reading through pages of Linux command line tool manuals.  There's tools to cut columns out of files, convert word documents to text, count lines and much much more.

and then, once your bored with that, here's a link to an article I wrote for PHP Builder a long time ago, showing you how to write your own pipe processors in PHP.

https://phpbuilder.com/php-and-shell-scripting-using-pipes/

Above all have fun, you can do some amazing stuff with quite a small number of tools.